# What order can a $2\times 2$ integer matrix be?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

There's no non-trivial integer $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $A^5=I_2$.

Some time algo, I proved this by pure algebraic manipulation. I took a generic matrix, calculated its fith power and  set equal to the identity. The only solution was the trivial one. (Actually, to save time, I calculated $A^2$ and $A^{-3}$, which was easier.) Now, the details of this proof are uninteresting and the procedure is straightforward, so I won't discuss in detail the proof (or, rather, check).

My question is if there's any deeper reason for there not to exist such a matrix. There do exist matrices of order ($1$,) $2$, $3$, $4$ and $6$, however. So are there more allowed orders? What's the underlying result?

Comment: No, these are all, with $\phi(n)\mid 2$, i.e., a divisor of the degree of the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_d$. And $\phi(n)=1$ or $2$ exactly if and only if $n=1,2,3,4,6$.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich. I'll look into that, hopping from one thm to the other.

Comment: I came up with an easy proof. The only allowed eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$, and the same goes for $\det(A)$. A short reasoning on the characteristic polynomial of $A$ yields that if $A$ is eventually idempotent, then $|\text{tr}(A)|\leq 2$. This leaves a few cases to check one by one and the proof will end satisfactorily.

Comment: Luca, very good. But the standard proof (see the duplicate) is also very easy, by showing that the order $n$ has to satisfy $\phi(n)\mid 2$. So I don't see a need for a different proof.